# How to specify a sync source when adding a new member to a MongoDB replicaset?

Tags: replication, mongodb, restore

Recently we had a machine physically destroyed, so our replicaset is now: Primary - Secondary - Arbiter (250G on disk, 20G (70hrs) oplog).

So, I'm trying to add a new member (4.4.10) to the replicaset (4.2.5), ( `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.2" } )` has been already done )
but when I'm adding it, the primary simply... crash after 2-3 minutes.

The machine load grows to 4k ! (only load, not CPU, not Memory)

We didn't have a downtime because the secondary became primary and after mongod services restart, the original primary took its place again.

The machines don't have any snapshot / lvm / zfs system available, so i can't take a snapshot.

My next attempt should be to do an `rs.syncFrom('[secondary]')` quickly after the `rs.add({ host:'[new secondary]', priority: 0, votes: 0 })`.
But if the primary crash and then the `rs.syncfrom()` make a new crash on the last machine, it will be a bad moment for us.

Is it possible to specify a *'syncFrom'* info at the same moment of adding the new member ?
(Or any other solution)

Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Do you have different mongo version on your machines?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the actuals machines (primary, secondary, arbiter) are in 4.2.5.
The new member is 4.4.10, but I can change it to 4.2.5 and do upgrade later.
The objective is to replace all actual machines in 4.2.5 with new machines in 4.4.10

Comment: Did you have a look at the mongod logfiles?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Only on the crash timestamp : `2021-12-01T16:08:03.007+0000 E  -        [ftdc] Assertion: Location13538: couldn't open [/proc/2269/stat] Too many open files src/mongo/util/processinfo_linux.cpp 76`
I didn't saw any error during the load increase